# KVM Switch for Monitors Only

Tags: multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I am wondering if I need a KVM switch to change monitors only, instead of other input peripherals. I have a work laptop, and Mac Mini that have their own keyboard/mouse, therefore my current setup is:

**Laptop:**
Keyboard A, Mouse A attached to laptop which displays on Screen A

**Mac:**
Keyboard B, Mouse B attached to Mac, which displayed on Screen B

I would like to continue using *keyboard/mouse A* with the laptop, and *keyboard/mouse B* with the Mac but switch between monitors so I can display the laptop or Mac on both screens.

Do I need a KVM switch to achieve this, since it would only change what device is being displayed on the monitors, not the keyboard/mouse. Or is their another approach to change between display monitors only?

Comment: The entire point of a KVM is the ability to switch which system with your keyboard.  So No, there isn't going to be a KVM, that only switches your monitor.  Now, you can get a KVM with a button, and simply NOT connect a keyboard and mouse and use the button on the device itself to do that.  However, most monitors, allow you to have 2 inputs.

Comment: @Ramhound Would there be a way to achieve what I want without a KVM switch?

Comment: Yes; Most monitors support 2 inputs.  You can switch between the two inputs using a button on the monitor.  There are also devices that only switch displays, they are NOT called KVMs, which is the reason I said your not going to find a KVM that only allows you to switch the monitor (unless it has a physical button and you just ignore the mouse and keyboard).